# NVD3 - Use superscript in axis label

Tags: d3.js, unicode, nvd3.js, exponent

**TLDR**: My NVD3 chart's Y-Axis label is "**Molecular density (kg/m^3)**" but I would like it instead to be "**Molecular density (kg/m<sup>3</sup>)**".

I am currently using NVD3 JavaScript library to generate some plots. I only have access to the JavaScript layer in this case, and I would like to use format using superscript in one of the axis labels.

I tried to use HTML, but the HTML tag instead gets printed as it is. Could you please suggest what is the best way to use superscript formatting in axis labels? Here's an example that you could run:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'lineChart',
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 80,
                    left: 55
                },
                x: function(d){ return d.x; },
                y: function(d){ return d.y; },
                useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Timeline',
                    tickFormat: function(d) {
                        return d3.time.format('%B %d')(new Date(d))
                    },
                    ticks: 6,
                    showMaxMin: false
                },
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Molecular density (kg/m^3)',
                    tickFormat: function(d){
                        return d3.format('.02f')(d);
                    },
                    axisLabelDistance: -10,
                    showMaxMin: false
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.data = [{"key":"K7 molecules","values":[{"x":1435708800000,"y":8},{"x":1435795200000,"y":9},{"x":1435881600000,"y":8},{"x":1435968000000,"y":8},{"x":1436054400000,"y":9},{"x":1436140800000,"y":9},{"x":1436227200000,"y":8},{"x":1436313600000,"y":8},{"x":1436400000000,"y":9},{"x":1436486400000,"y":9},{"x":1436572800000,"y":7},{"x":1436659200000,"y":8}],"area":true,"color":"#0CB3EE"},{"key":"N41 type C molecules","values":[{"x":1435708800000,"y":8},{"x":1435795200000,"y":7},{"x":1435881600000,"y":8},{"x":1435968000000,"y":9},{"x":1436054400000,"y":7},{"x":1436140800000,"y":9},{"x":1436227200000,"y":8},{"x":1436313600000,"y":9},{"x":1436400000000,"y":9},{"x":1436486400000,"y":9},{"x":1436572800000,"y":9},{"x":1436659200000,"y":8}],"area":true,"color":"#383838"}];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-nvD3 Line Chart</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.1/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution for this might be to use the [Unicode superscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) character: `³`.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'lineChart',
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 80,
                    left: 55
                },
                x: function(d){ return d.x; },
                y: function(d){ return d.y; },
                useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Timeline',
                    tickFormat: function(d) {
                        return d3.time.format('%B %d')(new Date(d))
                    },
                    ticks: 6,
                    showMaxMin: false
                },
                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Molecular density (kg/m³)',
                    tickFormat: function(d){
                        return d3.format('.02f')(d);
                    },
                    axisLabelDistance: -10,
                    showMaxMin: false
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.data = [{"key":"K7 molecules","values":[{"x":1435708800000,"y":8},{"x":1435795200000,"y":9},{"x":1435881600000,"y":8},{"x":1435968000000,"y":8},{"x":1436054400000,"y":9},{"x":1436140800000,"y":9},{"x":1436227200000,"y":8},{"x":1436313600000,"y":8},{"x":1436400000000,"y":9},{"x":1436486400000,"y":9},{"x":1436572800000,"y":7},{"x":1436659200000,"y":8}],"area":true,"color":"#0CB3EE"},{"key":"N41 type C molecules","values":[{"x":1435708800000,"y":8},{"x":1435795200000,"y":7},{"x":1435881600000,"y":8},{"x":1435968000000,"y":9},{"x":1436054400000,"y":7},{"x":1436140800000,"y":9},{"x":1436227200000,"y":8},{"x":1436313600000,"y":9},{"x":1436400000000,"y":9},{"x":1436486400000,"y":9},{"x":1436572800000,"y":9},{"x":1436659200000,"y":8}],"area":true,"color":"#383838"}];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-nvD3 Line Chart</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.1/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data" class="with-3d-shadow with-transitions"></nvd3>
    
  </body>

</html>
```